# Chrome iOS - Loading indicator when applying class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, google-chrome, css-transitions

For some reason, my page displays the loading indicator on Chrome, when applying a class to a section with css transition. The class adds a bottom value that makes the section slide up. And I think this loading is causing the address bar to be 'active', and won't slide up again. And thus covering my navigation bar. I'm using iPhone 4, iOS5.

I've tried to pin-point what might be causing this, because it's not there on desktop Chrome, or on Safari on the iphone. And it only happens while the class is being applied, and the animation is activated, and also after.

The page has a google map, and I'm collecting data from an XML document using $.ajax. This is however not causing the problem, cause I've tried disabling everything in the js-file, except the click handler that applies the class.

Here's the CSS:

```
#main_bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -297px;
    width: 300%;
    height: 384px;
    background-color: #ececec;
    -webkit-transition-property: bottom, left;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

#main_bottom.active {
    bottom: 36px;
}
```

I'm using this to apply the class:

```
$(document).on('click', '#main_bottom > section:not(#gps) > a', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $($main_bottom).toggleClass('active');
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="/">Choose nearest shop
    <div class="bigarrow"></div>
</a>
```

What could be causing this? It seems to be related to the animation somehow, not sure why. Could it be the absolute positioning, along with the css transition? If I'm allowed to link to the current live site, I'd be happy to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

I found it was because of the `<a href="/">`. Even though `e.preventDefault()`; was set, this still caused Chrome to do 'something' with the href.